A weird result when use aligned with sqrt for multiple lines
I'm trying to write an equation in which sqrt function is too long and I use aligned to break into multiple lines inside sqrt
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{(\tilde{\textbf{w}_i} - \tilde{\textbf{w}}_j)^T(\tilde{\textbf{w}_i} - \tilde{\textbf{w}}_j)}
&= \sqrt{
    \begin{aligned}
    (\Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_i - \mu) - \Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_j - \mu))^T\\
     & \times (\Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_i - \mu) - \Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_j - \mu))
    \end{aligned}} \\
& = \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
& = F_1 * F_2
\end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation}


Here is my result:

The block \times (\Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_i - \mu)... should be aligned left instead
It has a picture here if you don't see it please open this page in private mode. I dunno why.

It should be \mathbf and not \textbf. It would be also preferable to do \tilde{\mathbf{w}}_{i}

Thank you for point it out for me @egreg. I just know it now . Normally no one does this ;((

See also split.

You missed a & in the inner aligned:
  &= \sqrt{
      \begin{aligned}
       & (\Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_i - \mu) - \Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_j - \mu))^T\\
       & \times (\Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_i - \mu) - \Sigma^{-1/2}(\textbf{w}_j - \mu))
      \end{aligned}} \\

